# ScaledTranslation and X/Y inconsistency in pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, transformation, dpi

**Context**

I'm working on a python function that plots data (a `plt.plot` wrapper) with arrow and name at the end of each axe, and an option to show the scale at given coordinates (`sclorg` in the example below). The text position must react as expected when the window is resized, when `subplots_adjust` is used...
I can't use the `SubplotZero` function due to some of its limitations.

**Setup**

conda 23.7.3
python 3.11.4
matplotlib: 3.7.1 (anaconda's latest)

Also tested with:
matplotlib: 3.7.2 (updated with pip)

**MWE**

This MWE is not that minimal, sorry! I want to avoid good but irrelevant answers because of a too minimal example.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plot data
x=np.linspace(0,10,101)
y=np.sin(x)
# basic drawing
fig=plt.figure()
p1,=plt.plot(x,y,figure=fig)
ax=p1.axes
plt.show(block=False)
# X and Y constant offset
offsetX=mpl.transforms.ScaledTranslation(.09,0,fig.dpi_scale_trans)
offsetY=mpl.transforms.ScaledTranslation(0,.09,fig.dpi_scale_trans)   # <- Problem here?
# axes labels
ax.annotate("theta (rad)",xy=(1,0),va='center',ha='left'  ,clip_on=False,xycoords=ax.transAxes+offsetX)
ax.annotate("U (V)"      ,xy=(0,1),ha='center',va='bottom',clip_on=False,xycoords=ax.transAxes+offsetY)
# scale origin
sclorg=np.array((1,-.75))
# x and Y ticks steps
xstep=ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()
xstep=xstep[1]-xstep[0]
ystep=ax.yaxis.get_majorticklocs()
ystep=ystep[1]-ystep[0]
# scale drawing
ax.annotate("",xy=sclorg+np.array((xstep,0)),xytext=sclorg,arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",lw=1,shrinkA=0,shrinkB=0,mutation_scale=10),annotation_clip=False)
ax.annotate("",xy=sclorg+np.array((0,ystep)),xytext=sclorg,arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",lw=1,shrinkA=0,shrinkB=0,mutation_scale=10),annotation_clip=False)
# scale text
ax.text(sclorg[0]+xstep/2,sclorg[1],str(xstep)+" rad",ha='center',va='top',transform=ax.transData-offsetY)
ax.text(sclorg[0],sclorg[1]+ystep/2,str(ystep)+" V",ha='left',va='center',transform=ax.transData+offsetX)
```

**Problem**

I want to shift some text by the same fixed amount in two situations:

1. the axes names
2. the optional scale texts

The problem appears when I save the plot in png/pdf:
PNG: I get what's displayed (and what I want) without any problem.
PDF: the "ylabel" vertical position looks correct, but the x scale text is not.

**Some investigations**

1. The problem must come from `offsetY`...
   `fig.dpi_scale_trans?` returns some text, among which is `Affine2D().scale(200.0)`.
2. Some Google researches help me find another peculiar value of DPI: 72.
   I tried to replace in `offsetY` the value `.09` by `.09*72/200`
   After saving:
   PNG: I get what's displayed and expected: both "ylabel" and x scale text are shifted to an undesired position.
   PDF: the "ylabel" is shifted, but the x scale text has good vertical position.
3. I tried to save with `plt.savefig("sine.pdf",dpi=200)` but the `dpi` argument is kind of ignored.

**Gallery**

Original result in PNG (what I'ld like to have in pdf):
[image: Original result, PNG]

Original result in PDF:
[image: Original result, PDF]

With `offsetY` corrected, in PNG:
[image: offsetY corrected, PNG]

With `offsetY` corrected, in PDF:
[image: offsetY corrected, PDF]